# How to buy application previously downloaded from GetJar?

Tags: applications

I have Agenda Widget Plus downloaded from **GetJar**. Now I would like to pay for it, because I find it very useful and I would like to reword author of this app. On **Play Store** it is listed as already installed and I cannot pay for it.

Any idea how can I do it?

Answer (score 4):

You will need to uninstall the app from your device and after that the Play store should allow you to purchase it.

Comment: Sorry, small mistake - in **Play Store** this application is listed as **PURCHASED**.  

When I'm trying to install it using **Play Store** web page, following error message appears:  
`Oops, we had trouble with this request. Please try again later.`  
I've already uninstalled application from my phone, cleared **Play Store** application cache, but it didn't help.

Comment: OK, it took about one week, but finally I was able to order the application. So **Chahk's** answer is correct. But it took a while, to make it working :-)